# How to convert Turkish letters to English ones in a URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, character, forum

I am using a forum software and i am having a lot of problems with that. I would like to turn this url:

```
forum/forum/26-5-seviye-köy-düzeni/
```

into:

```
forum/forum/26-5-seviye-koy-duzeni/
```

I would like to know if that is possible somehow.

The system is ipboard.

Comment: Define two arrays, one filled with Turkish characters, one filled with corresponding English characters. Then use `str_replace`. Checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @sinaza I believe OP wants to redirect a URL via .htaccess, not rewrite user input with PHP. Burak could you please edit your post to clarify?